# upload and save image with information

Tags: python, image, flask, upload

I am writing a flask web app, in which we can upload and save images in the file system. I also want to save images with little information like city, date to capture, etc .and include more features like sorting images with date, popular among users, sorting by the city .
how can I do that if I am saving images on file system, not a database?

```
   import os
   from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, 
   send_from_directory
   from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename


    app = Flask(__name__)

   APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
  UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'static/uploads')
  app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

 app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS'] = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg','gif'])
   def allowed_file(filename):
     return '.' in filename and \
       filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']


  @app.route('/')
    def index():
       return render_template('index.html')



@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
    def upload():
      file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
          filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
          file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',filename=filename))

   @app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
   def uploaded_file(filename):
        return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename)

  if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(port=4555)
```

Comment: Post the code as text instead of images to be able to copy & paste

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to access the exif data. Look at this package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ExifRead

```
import exifread
# Open image file for reading (binary mode)
f = open(path_name, 'rb')

# Return Exif tags
tags = exifread.process_file(f)
```

Comment: The link I provided tells you how. I also updated my answer with the relevant section to get the exif tags.

Comment: in future i will add features like, sort my images with city name or show top  ten images among user, recent upload images. do you think is this right approach to save data for every image?